# Want to find date based on input number C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to be able to find date based on input number(between 1-365). For e.g., if number entered as 40 then my program should output - **Date:9 Month:2**
I have tried the below code and was able to find dates for all months except January -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arryofdays = new int[] {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int temp = num;
    string date, month;

    for (int i = 0; i < arryofdays.Length; i++)
    {        
        temp = temp - arryofdays[i];
        if (temp < arryofdays[i + 1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Date:" + temp.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Month:" + (i+2).ToString());
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just try like this;

```
 var datetime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1).AddDays(40 - 1);
 var month = datetime.Month; //2
 var day = datetime.Day; //9
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,take arugment and also check it you can able to convert in int form or not, make your program type safe

and also check validation that days value will be between 1 and 365

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int days = 0;
            if (args.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(args[0], out days))
            {
                if (!(days < 1 || days > 366))
                {
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1).AddDays(days - 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", date.Day);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", date.Month);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("input vlaue  is not correct or not present");
            }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the type safe option. Surely will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arryofdays = new int[] {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int days = 0;
    int months = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < arryofdays.Length; i++) {
        if (num > arryofdays[i]) {
            num -= arryofdays[i]; 
            months++;            
        } else {
            days = num;
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Date:" + days.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Month:" + (months+1).ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Assuming `num = 40`, on the first iteration of the for loop, it'll check if `num > arryofdays[0]` which is if `40 > 31`. That'll return true, so 31 will be decremented from `num` making the value of `num` to be 9. `months`  will be incremented. On the next iteration (`i = 1`), it'll check if `num > arryofdays[1]` which is if `9 > 28` which means there are only 9 days and we `break` because we don't need to go any further.

Your output will be

> Date:9
>
> Month:2

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working for *JAN* month is, because on `temp = temp - arryofdays[i];` statement you are getting negative values if your inout is less than 31.

You can modify your code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace Rextester
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Your code goes here
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            int[] arryofdays = new int[] {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
            int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int temp = num;
            string date, month;

            for (int i = 0; i < arryofdays.Length; i++)
            {

                temp =(temp - arryofdays[i]);
                if (temp < arryofdays[i + 1] && temp >0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Date:" + temp.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Month:" + (i+2).ToString());
                    break;
                }else{//for handling first month
                    Console.WriteLine("Date:" +num);
                    Console.WriteLine("Month:" + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Working code : http://rextester.com/PAJQ64015

Hope that helps.